# Is there any cloudwatch alarm metric of RDS to check connectivity issues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I want to create cloudwatch alarm if I face connectivity issues with my database.
But I could not see any metric for that

Comment: Connectivity from where?

Comment: Check the RDS metrics section on the aws documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MonitoringOverview.html#monitoring-cloudwatch).  One of these should work for your monitoring goal.  Best of luck! :)